# NullReferenceException from SPService.Delete()

Tags: 2010, development

I have a sharepoint service that inherits from [SPDiagnosticsServiceBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spdiagnosticsservicebase(v=office.14).aspx).  When I deactivate the feature, I have the following code:

```
    public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPFarm farm = properties.Definition.Farm;

        if (farm != null)
        {
            LoggingService service = LoggingService.Local;

            if (service != null)
            {
                service.Delete();
            }
        }
     }
```

The line `service.Delete()` generates a NullReferenceException.  I don't understand how this can occur since I check for null immediately prior.  Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but, to my knowledge you can't delete timer jobs in a SandBoxed Solution. It has to be a Farm solution.

Another suggestion provided by [Aaron Han](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/aaron%20han%20-%20msft) for troubleshooting the issue further:

> As a final parting, have you downloaded Reflector to look at the
>   source for SPJobDefinition.Delete(), it does a lot of things that
>   could create null reference exceptions if theres an error in your
>   farm,
>
> Basically it tries to delete the timer job about 4 different ways
>   before it finally gives up and throws an error. Get Reflector, add all
>   the sharepoint dll's to it, then do a Search for "SPJobDefinition" and
>   have a look.

Comment: This was a farm solution.